# Syntax highlight does not work when code block is inside a blockquote

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Putting a syntax highlighting hint before a code block works:

```php
$code = "syntax highlight works";
return $code;
```

But putting it before a quoted code block fails:

> ```
> $code_in_quote = "syntax highlight fails";
> return $code;
> ```

The same goes for putting it inside the quote block:

> ```php
> $code_in_quote = "syntax highlight fails";
> return $code;
> ```

Putting `<!-- language: php -->` both before quote block and inside it changes nothing.

I'm not saying that "off by default" in quote block is a bug - it may be design feature I will not argue either way. **Not being able to turn highlight on** when I know source has it on looks like bug to me.

Screenshot from main site:

[image: screenshot of this problem]

Note that rendered HTML does contain `<code>` element all right:

[image: screenshot from page source]

Comment: I initially read your question wrong, then was sure this is a dupe. But I have yet to find it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if original has [meta-tag:status-completed] then it's a new bug in the same area, and please don't close it. If it's not completed, I'll gladly upvote original. But I wasn't able to find older reports of this.

Comment: I am still not convinced this is a bug; I suspect there is a reason that a blockquote does not apply syntax highlighting. You are quoting another source, and that source perhaps did not include highlighting. Or some such argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it's by design I don't agree with the design - at least turning it on with `<!-- language: php -->` if I know that source **did** include highlighting should be possible. I'm not saying that off by default is a bug, only that **the fact I can't turn it on is a bug**. Unless there is a way and I simply wasn't able to find it, of course.

Comment: Fair enough; an explicit code tag hint I'd support.

Comment: @Mołot I've corrected your syntax highlighting hints. You were using `<!-- language: php -->` when the correct hint is `<!-- language: lang-php -->`, you missed out on the "lang-". Now the example with the code hint _within_ the quote appears to work just fine.